# Use styled-jsx in react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-jsx

I am trying to use the styled-jsx library in a react component (created with create react app).

But I get the error:

> styled-jsx/css: if you are getting this error it means that your `css` tagged template literals were not transpiled.

I am not sure how to solve it or it is that this library for react componentes can not be used (It is the first time I use it).

```js
import React from 'react';
import css from 'styled-jsx/css'
// import './styles';

export default function MyComponent(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <div key={props.value}>{props.label}</div>
            <style jsx>{button}</style>
        </>
    )
}

const button = css`div { color: hotpink; }`
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you add the babel plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the babel plugin as per these [instructions](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx).

1. run styled-jsx/webpack before babel-loader
2. add styled-jsx/babel to the babel loader plugins

The error does not suggest an issue with your mark-up more how the code is being transpiled, but you could test by simplifying it:

```
import React from 'react';
import css from 'styled-jsx/css'

export default function MyComponent(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <div key={props.value}>{props.label}</div>
            <button>Click Me</button>

            <style jsx>{`
              button {
                color: hotpink;
              }
`            `}</style>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Vite to install React, gives access to all configurations in
vite.config.js Here is my working config: Remember to restart dev script.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      babel: {
        parserOpts: {
          "plugins": ["styled-jsx/babel"]
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

EDIT: Here's a link on how to do it in Create-React-App
[CRA - with Styled JSX](https://dev.greglobinski.com/styled-jsx-create-react-app/)