# styled-jsx works inline but not as module

Tags: webpack, babeljs, preact, css-in-js, styled-jsx

I've added styled-jsx to my Preact (set up with this [TS template](https://github.com/preactjs-templates/typescript)) project, and can style things inline via the `<style>` tag with no issues, e.g.:

```js
    <div>
      <h1>Hello{name && `, ${name}`}!</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleNameSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={input} onInput={handleInput} />
        <button type="submit" className="test">
          Update {input && `as ${input}`}
        </button>
      </form>
      <style jsx>
        {`
          h1 {
            color: red;
          }

          .test {
            color: blue;
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </div>
```

But if I extract that style into a separate `css` variable (either in the same file or externally) while following [their instructions](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#external-css-and-styles-outside-of-the-component) I get the following error:

```
if you are getting this error it means that your `css` tagged template literals were not transpiled.
```

There's a few answers/solutions to it on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63966323/use-styled-jsx-in-react-component) and [Github](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx/issues/685) but they all involve changing the webpack config -- and I don't have a webpack config. Looks like there isn't one out of the box with `preact-cli`. I've added the babel rule to my `babelrc` as recommended:

```
{
  "presets": ["preact-cli/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-jsx/babel", { "optimizeForSpeed": true }]]
}
```

I didn't install any extra `macros` or plugins from babel, however, as that was not in the original instructions in the styled-jsx readme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.babelrc` isn't supported at the moment in Preact-CLI, though this is due to an odd bug that I haven't yet been able to track down. Sorry about that.

You do however still have a way to edit the Webpack config, and that's with your `preact.config.js`, [the docs for which can be found here](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli#webpack). In your case, what you'll want is the following:

`preact.config.js`

```js
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    const { rule } = helpers.getLoadersByName(config, 'babel')[0];
    const babelConfig = rule.options;

    babelConfig.plugins.push(['styled-jsx/babel', { 'optimizeForSpeed': true }]);
}
```

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: This works! Thanks. I'm a little confused though, because the preact cli docs specifically mention a babelrc, and the typescript template includes one. So why isn't babelrc supported? Or is it not supported by styled-jsx?

Comment: So it should be supported, hence the docs, but I don't believe it's working as intended at the moment. This was just brought up to me last week, and I'm not sure how long it's been broken. Need to investigate that some more. The TS template having one is a relic that I need to remove, and that would never get picked up in the location it's at. We'd only detect a `.babelrc` in the root folder automatically. Sorry about that, I'll put this higher in the list of issues I need to fix. Thanks for alerting me about the TS template!

Comment: Upon doing some digging, this is actually working as intended. The docs do say that if you want to modify the config, `.babelrc` is not the way to do it. Use your `preact.config.js`. For whatever reason Babel cannot correctly resolve the preset (I could not discern why this was, baffles me), so using `.babelrc` is only for when you want to override the default config. As for why that `.babelrc` existed in the template, it was for Jest, originally. But the `jest-preset-preact` lib handles that now.